# Visual Studio 2015 Build Speed is slower in comparison to 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2015, build, linker, scons, cl

We're in the process of updating our Windows build to Visual Studio 2015 from 2013. Now that the code is compiling we've noticed the build times have increased. i.e. Up from 14 to 17 minutes. This is somewhat problematic.

vs2015 may be producing better optimized code. But for on-commit build optimized code is not a priority. Instead we'd prefer a fast build which avoids queues and delays.

Are there any default options in vs2015 that we can toggle off to improve our build speed? i.e. That have changed since 2013.

I should note that we use SCons. So the main tools affected are cl and link. i.e. Rather than Visual Studio / msbuild.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting:

```
env['CCFLAGS']= '/0d'
env['LINKFLAGS'] = '/0d'
```

From ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1ack8f1.aspx )

> /Od disables optimization, speeding compilation and simplifying
>   debugging.

Comment: I'll give it a shot